# Event when item added to a combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

In WinForm, when items are added to a ComboBox, which event is fired?

Thanks.

Comment: how are you adding items to the control? if you are allowing the combo box to be editable, once the control has lost focus, the selected item changed event will occur, and you can determine if the value is new there.

Comment: I use addrange to add items to the combobox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no events fired when an item is added to a ComboBox - presumably because you're in control of when items are added.

Comment: yupp! looking through the code in Reflector, it doesn't look like any event is raised.

Comment: So, is there any alternative way to do something automatically after  items add to a combobox?

Comment: Yes, ensure all your adds go through a AddItemToCombobox(item As Object) {...} method of your own devising that does your extra stuff.

Comment: You might be able to do something fancy if you derive from ComboBox - but it could be a fair amount of effort for little gain.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of assistance Jfly.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a property on your datasource of your `ComboBox`, and on the set of that property you could raise a event.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is still open, but if you're still looking for it - I ended up creating a customer sortable combobox by deriving from ComboBox, then creating a new parameter called "AddItem()", which called this.Items.Add and extra code.

This may help you out as the event would be fired every time you add an item using AddItem().